# Reading Google spread sheet without using any credential in Java

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I am working with the google Spreadsheet and wanted to read all the data from it without using any credential.json file.

What I actually want is, If I have been provided a URL for spreadsheets then I should be able to read the data without using any client secrets.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate yourself yo use the API even if the sheet is public.

You could try just to make an HTTP request to actually download the information, take a look at this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70) to see all the formats you can use.

For exemple download/read the file as CSV:

```
curl 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pObOjcxHEZHDb0DOA8mxcO3HY_koVcTNdmzjjE7Sj9w/export?format=csv'
```

Comment: On just clicking the link I downloaded a csv file of your spreadsheet, why you say it isn't working?